# JCSMP Solace Connection

Tags: java, eclipse, solace-mq, solace

I am working on creating a Solace Connection. I am using JCSMP package within Solace for that

```
import com.solacesystems.jcsmp.JCSMPException;
import com.solacesystems.jcsmp.JCSMPFactory;
import com.solacesystems.jcsmp.JCSMPProperties;
import com.solacesystems.jcsmp.JCSMPSession;
import com.solacesystems.jcsmp.JCSMPStreamingPublishEventHandler;
import com.solacesystems.jcsmp.TextMessage;
import com.solacesystems.jcsmp.Topic;
import com.solacesystems.jcsmp.XMLMessageProducer;
```

in ways like:

```
 final JCSMPProperties properties = new JCSMPProperties();
```

So i am trying to read up on it to get a better idea. But I cannot find any documentation online. And I have spent like 2 days searching for it before posting here.

Can anyone guide me for the same.

Thanks

Comment: The JCSMP package should contain a large quantity of sample applications. I would suggest starting with the intro samples; they are easy to follow and contain minimal code that will show you how to create a connection to Solace.

Answer (score 3):

I realize this answer is extremely after the fact, but Solace now has their API documentation available online here:

http://dev.solacesystems.com/docs/enterprise-api-docs/

Note that I currently work for Solace but provide the link because I believe it is what is being requested in the question.